# How do I rename (not move) a file in Java 7?

Tags: java, file-io, path, nio, java-7

I'm a bit confused with all these new File I/O classes in JDK7.

Let's say, I have a `Path` and want to rename the file it represents. How do I specify the new name, when again a `Path` is expected?

```
Path p = /* path to /home/me/file123 */;
Path name = p.getName(); /* gives me file123 */
name.moveTo(/* what now? */); /* how to rename file123 to file456? */
```

*NOTE: Why do I need **JDK7**? Handling of **symbolic links**!*

Problem is: I have to do it with files whose names and locations are known at runtime. So, what I need, is a **safe** method (without exceptional side-effects) to create a new name-Path of some old name-Path.

```
Path newName(Path oldName, String newNameString){
    /* magic */ 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a path string and you need to create a Path instance. You can do this with the getPath method or resolve. Here's one way:

```
Path dir = oldFile.getParent();        
Path fn = oldFile.getFileSystem().getPath(newNameString);
Path target = (dir == null) ? fn : dir.resolve(fn);        
oldFile.moveTo(target);
```

Note that it checks if parent is null (looks like your solution don't do that).

Answer (score 61):

In JDK7, [Files.move()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) provides a short and concise syntax for renaming files:

```
Path newName(Path oldName, String newNameString) {
    return Files.move(oldName, oldName.resolveSibling(newNameString));
}
```

First we're getting the Path to the new file name using [Path.resolveSibling()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolveSibling(java.lang.String))
and the we use [Files.move()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) to do the actual renaming.

Comment: This has the added bonus of being platform independent, unlike moveTo that can break occasionally.

Answer (score 4):

OK, after trying everything out, it seems I found the right method:

```
// my helper method
Path newName(Path oldFile, String newNameString){
    // the magic is done by Path.resolve(...)
    return oldFile.getParent().resolve(newNameString);
}

// so, renaming is done by:
oldPath.moveTo(newName(oldFile, "newName"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html) there's a class called [FileNameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html). This does a ton of stuff wrt. file path names and will (amongst other things) reliably split up path names etc. I think that should get you a long way towards what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I need symbolic-links-aware APIs. All these Apache Commons stuff is at best Java-5-compatible, but mostly Java-1.4.

Comment: Does it not help you purely in terms of splitting up and reassembling filenames, and you can use Java 7 symlink aware stuff to actually perform the copy/rename ?

Comment: Good functionality for handling of symlinks is provided only by JDK7, because it has low-level (binary level) bindings to the operating system.

Comment: I'm afraid, that such splitting up and reassembling could in some circumstances lead to errors. But wait, I'm now experimenting with `Path.resolve(String name)`. I think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination path is identical to the source path *except for the name of the file*, it will be renamed rather than moved.

So for your example, the moveto path should be

```
/home/me/file456
```

Comment: So I just can create a new `Path`? Is there something simpler than: Path newName = Paths.get(name.getParent().toString()+pathSeparator+"newName"); ?

Comment: Yes, now the question is: how to create such path in a safe way, so that no exceptional circumstances would cause it to fail.

Comment: I could attempt to describe how you could take the original path, strip off the name 'file123' concatenate 'file456' instead and invoke `name.moveTo()` but since I don't really know Java, I'd be guessing. What I'm **sure** about is that a *move* becomes a *rename* if only the filename is different.

Answer (score -2):

If you can't get Java to do what you want with Unix I recommend Python scripts (run by your Java program).  Python has get support for Unix scripting and it's not Perl :)   This might sound inelegant to you but really in a larger program you'll benefit from using the right tool for the job.