# How to rename a file without making another file (Java)

Tags: java, rename

I am looking for a away to rename a file to a string. renameTo only takes another file as a parameter, but I want it to take a string. So basically, how do I implement this method here?

```
public static void renameFile(File toBeRenamed, String new_name) {

}
```

I would like to rename the file "toBeRenamed" to "new_name". Do I have to make another file called new_name, or is there some workaround? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks for the answer Luiggi. Here is a pic of the new error:

[image]

Comment: duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914474/how-do-i-rename-not-move-a-file-in-jdk7

Comment: @KickButtowski not exactly a duplicate. I could say very related.

Comment: A `File` is just a wrapper around a `String`, and a whole lot of methods for doing file-related stuff.  So when you create a `File` object, all you're really getting is a `String`.  Can you please explain why you don't want to do this?  It doesn't actually create a real file on the disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class doesn't represent the physic file in the hard drive, it is just an **abstract representation**. Creating a new instance of `File` class doesn't mean you are creating a physical file.

By knowing this, you can rename your file using a new `File` without worrying about creating new physical files. Code adapted from [Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158777/1065197):

```
public static void renameFile(File toBeRenamed, String new_name)
    throws IOException {
    //need to be in the same path
    File fileWithNewName = new File(toBeRenamed.getParent(), new_name);
    if (fileWithNewName.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("file exists");
    }
    // Rename file (or directory)
    boolean success = toBeRenamed.renameTo(fileWithNewName);
    if (!success) {
        // File was not successfully renamed
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Based on your question update and on this comment:

> I took a pic of the error. "Unhandled Exception Type IO Exception"

Looks one of these:

1. You don't know how to handle checked exceptions.

   To do this, you should wrap the method that throws the `Exception` (or subclass) in a `try-catch` statement:

   ```
   String new_name = getFilename(file);
   try {
       renameFiles(files[i], new_name);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       //handle the exception
       //using a basic approach
       e.printStacktrace();
   }
   ```

   More info: [Java Tutorial. Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).
2. You don't want your method to throw a checked exception. In this case, it would be better to throw an unchecked exception instead, so you don't need to handle the exception manually. This can be done by throwing a new instance of `RuntimeException` or a subclass of this:

   ```
   public static void renameFile(File toBeRenamed, String new_name) {
       File fileWithNewName = new File(new_name);
       if (fileWithNewName.exists()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("file exists.");
       }
       // Rename file (or directory)
       boolean success = toBeRenamed.renameTo(fileWithNewName);
       if (!success) {
           // File was not successfully renamed
       }
   }
   ```

   More info in the link posted in the above section.
3. You don't want to throw an exception at all. In this case, it would be better to at least return a value to know if the file was exactly renamed:

   ```
   public static boolean renameFile(File toBeRenamed, String new_name) {
       //need to be in the same path
       File fileWithNewName = new File(toBeRenamed.getParent(), new_name);
       if (fileWithNewName.exists()) {
           return false;
       }
       // Rename file (or directory)
       return toBeRenamed.renameTo(fileWithNewName);
   }
   ```

   And update your code accordingly:

   ```
   String new_name = getFilename(file);
   boolean result = renameFiles(files[i], new_name);
   if (!result) {
       //the file couldn't be renamed
       //notify user about this
       System.out.println("File " + files[i].getName() + " couldn't be updated.");
   }
   ```

Which one to choose? Will depend entirely on your taste. If I were you, I would use the third option for a quick dirty or learning phase work, but for a real world application I would use second option but using my own custom exception that extends from `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Hi Luiggi, that was a great answer and made alot of sense. However, I am having a bit of trouble getting it to work, I'll keep you updated, and I'll mark your answer as the answer once I'm done.

Comment: I took a pic of the error. "Unhandled Exception Type IO Exception" So Yes :)

Comment: Please feel free to open my screenshot in a new tab to make it bigger. I'm trying to go through all the files in a folder and rename each one. There is nothing wrong with my "getFileName" method, which returns a string which I want to make the new file name. Sorry that this was kind of a silly question, I can't believe I didn't realize I wouldn't be making any real files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53921/discussion-between-user3133300-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Comment: This looks more like making a copy than renaming. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnK official javadoc [`File#renameTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)): *Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname. Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could be useful for you

```
// File (or directory) with old name
File file = new File("oldname");

// File (or directory) with new name
File file2 = new File("newname");
if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

// Rename file (or directory)
boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
if (!success) {
    // File was not successfully renamed
}
```

This is extracted from a similar question [Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java)

Comment: I have tried that, but then I would need to create two files. I just want to rename a file to a string without having to make a new file.

Comment: @user3133300 you do not create a real physical file when creating a new instance of `File` class. Check my answer.