# Rename non empty directory issue using Java NIO

Tags: java, file, java-8, file-move

According to:
[How do I rename (not move) a file in JDK7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914474/how-do-i-rename-not-move-a-file-in-jdk7)

I'm trying to rename folder name of not empty folder with java NIO

My result ,  is new directory created without files inside and not delete old one.

The code i used but it doesn't work:

```
  try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env)) {
      Path oldPath = fs.getPath("/some/directory2");
      Files.move(oldPath, oldPath.resolve("/some/directory_replaced2_2"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
 } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What I'm missing  ? ( I want only rename folder)

Comment: that's interesting, if I simply do `Path oldPath = Paths.get("/Users/me/Desktop/Folder");
        Files.move(oldPath, oldPath.resolve("/Users/me/Desktop/Folder2"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` this works just fine

Comment: add inside /Users/me/Desktop/Folder , other files...

Comment: that's right, that folder is not empty, it has files and sub-folders with files

Comment: how do you initialize the FileSystem  uri , FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri,env) ?

Comment: look at my example *again*. I don't initialize that, since I don't need to

Comment: Sorry , I'll update my question  , cause i thought that is not important...i'm working with ZIP content and using FileSystem...in this case it is not working...

Comment: Do not edit your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Instead, post a new question, thanks. Reverted the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename directory using [java.nio.file.Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) method and then `copy` the files with `Files.walkFileTree`:

> To move a file tree may involve copying rather than moving directories and this can be done using the *copy* method in conjunction with the Files.walkFileTree utility method.

You can follow [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html):

> ```
> import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
>
> Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
> ```
>
> the method is most often used with the file tree recursion mechanism. For more information, see [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Comment: @ user7294900 , can you suggest an example please ?

Comment: @VitalyT added an example from java tutorial